# Systemd and unavailable cifs mounts

Tags: boot, fstab, systemd

I use a Lubuntu 16.04 EEE-PC with Kernel 4.4.0-38 which was upgraded from a 14.04 version.

I have in /etc/fstab the line

```
//192.168.1.99/public /mnt/NAS cifs credentials=/home/hias/.geheim,iocharset=utf8      0       0
```

which did not give me problems in 14.04, even if the server in question was not running.

In 16.04 the system is not booting using systemd. When I boot with upstart (via GRUB) it works as before. When I outcomment the line in fstab, I can boot with systemd.

So I guess this is a systemd issue.

Any opinions how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add nofail to your fstab entry to avoid dropping into emergency mode when mounting a filesystem that may not be present.

```
//192.168.1.99/public /mnt/NAS cifs nofail,credentials=/home/hias/.geheim,iocharset=utf8      0       0
```

source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/fstab.5.html